# How do I render a custom set of screen coordinates in Opengl

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Is there any way to render a different set of screen coordinates than the standard equidistant grid between -1,-1 to 1,1?
I am not talking about a transformation that can be accomplished by transformations in the vertex shader.
Specifically ES2 would be nice, but any version is fine.

Is this even directly OpenGl related or is the standard grid typically provided by plumbing libraries?

Comment: Why exactly you don't want a transformation inside a vertex shader? This is how it's supposed to work.

Comment: This is not generally possible with a transformation in a vertex shader. Vertex shader transformations map vertices into the screen coordinate system. They do not allow you to specify for which x,y rays in screen space the scene is rendered.

Comment: @MaVo159: Your commen't doesn't really make sense. The window space tansformation and rasterization rules are not defined by the VS, that is true. But they are defined by the GL spec and the various GL state variables. So it is exaclty clear what will happen, and all of this can be taken into account in the VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't any other way. The values you write to `gl_Position` in the vertex (or tesselation or geometry) shader are *clip space* coordinates. The GPU will convert these to normalized device space (the "[-1,1] grid") by dividing by the w coordinate (after the actual primitive clipping, of course) and will finally use the viewport parameters to transform the results to *window space*.

There is no way to directly use window coordinates when you want to use the rendering pipeline. There are some operations which bypass large parts of that pipeline, like frambuffer blitting, which provides a limited way to draw some things directly to the framebuffer.

However, working with pixel coordinates isn't hard to achieve. You basically have to invert the transformations the GPU will be doing. While typically "ortho" matrices are used for this, the only required operations are a scale and a translation, which boils down to a fused multiply-add per component, so you can implement this extremely efficient in the vertex shader.